# Validation libraries not found when Updating to Payara 4.1.1.174

Tags: eclipse, validation, payara

I'm using Payara Server 4.1.1.171 with a Webproject in Eclipse Oxygen without any problems since a long time. I have my domainfiles outside the program directories so I can switch easily between version (which I did a couple of times before).

Now, when I want to switch to Version 4.1.1.174 my project doesn't compile anymore because the imports for

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
javax.validation.constraints.Size
javax.validation.constraints.Email
javax.validation.ConstraintValidator
javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext
```

etc. are not found anymore.

I'm aware that the bean-validation.jar has been renamed to validation.jar. But it seems that Eclipse doesn't add it to the glassfish library list, for a reason I don't know.

When I copy the validation.jar to endorsed, it is included (automatically) in the glassfish system library list, but the problems only change -> now the hibernate.Email constraint isn't found anymore.

EDIT: 
Even if I rename the new validation-api.jar to bean-validator.api, which is found as a solution in some places, it doesn't work. Eclipse won't add the jar file to the Systemlibrary. When I deploy the project on the new server it works perfectly. So I guess the only problem is with the Eclipse Glassfishtools that don't add the correct validation jars!

Answer (score 1):

You need at least the [**Bean Validation API 2.0.0.Final**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.0.Final) JAR ([`validation-api-2.0.0.Final.jar`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/validation/validation-api/2.0.0.Final/validation-api-2.0.0.Final.jar)) on your Java classpath.

See also [*Changes between Bean Validation 2.0 and 1.1*](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/)

Comment: Hi Howlger, your are right. This is exactely the problem. Payara provides the validation.jar in the modules path of the installation but the eclipse glassfish tools don't use it in the system class path which is normally built automatically.

Comment: this does not answer why it is not added by default in Eclipse/payara. same for payara version 5

Comment: @usertest Obviously this is a bug of the GlassFish Tools plug-in. The answer only says that in the workaround for this bug, make sure to add the correct Bean Validation API version (version 2.0 instead of 1.1). Otherwise, it leads to the problems described in the question. Unfortunately, the development of the plugin seems to have been discontinued, so that no solution for the root problem is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

I added it to my class path in netbeans and the compilation rises no more exceptions. But the question is: 
Why we didn't need to add it to the class-path when using Payara 171?

Answer (score 0):

"Even if I rename the new validation-api.jar to bean-validator.api, which is found as a solution in some places, it doesn't work."

You must rename it to
bean-validator.jar
(not bean-validator.api)